# flutter waits a long time when I render a large image first time

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to show an image on my sd card with flutter. The image size is up to 10MB. and I load it with **Image.file** function.

the first time after launching the app. it needs to wait 3 or 4 seconds to show the image. but except for the first time, everything is OK.

Although flutter will cache the image in memory, IO is not the bottleneck. Does anyone knowns the reason? or is there any document about the flutter render pipeline?

Comment: I don't think the image is cached in memory. I guess some `setState()` is missing or at the wrong place and Flutter just doesn't know that it needs ti re-render. 10MB from a local storage is not a big image and shouldn't take 1sec to load.

Comment: the [ImageCache](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html) Class will handle image cache automatisk.  And there is no need to call `setState()`  because I just return an image widget without state changed.